# What standard of NFT to adopt when wanting to mint a set of nft to a collection and then mint NFT one by one to the collection

Tags: nft, program

I want to mint a set of NFT to a collection and then want to mint NFT one by one...what standard and procedure would be best in terms of tx cost would that be most efficient in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

A highly efficient and recommended approach is utilizing the Candy Machine.

I recommend exploring the resources provided in the Metaplex docs:

https://docs.metaplex.com/developer-tools/sugar/tutorials/my-first-candy-machine

Have a nice a day.